# Quirks mode and doctypes

Tags: javascript, css, doctype, quirks-mode

I'm developing a website:
http://parkoura.tk/ashkon/blog.php

I've never tried to develop something complicated such as this, and due to my inexperience I ran into the following:

In quirks mode (Gecko/Webkit), when no DTD is declared, the webpage is rendered fine.

When I do add a doctype (4.1 transitional or HTML5), to get the page to start working in IE, the scroller on the right of the page stops working.

If there are no magic fixes, I will have to rebuild the site – but I was wondering if you had any suggestions for me before I do that.

Comment: can you add a demo *when you add a doctype* to it?

Comment: As others have answered below, **validate your HTML**.  Valid HTML works much better as expected across browsers.

Comment: hello, here is the static http://parkoura.tk/ashkon/blog.html page with the doctype declaration... thanks a lot for the validator! I will try to fix all my problems tonight with that. I'll leave the question open just in case that doesn't work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by validating the code, that will show you that there are some errors in the markup:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fparkoura.tk%2Fashkon%2Fblog.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

For example, you have used `<header>` instead of `<head>`, you have mismatched tags, you have escaped a lot of quotation marks.

Fixing the worst errors will probably make the page work with a doctype also.

Answer (score 2):

Start here: [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://parkoura.tk/ashkon/blog.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Once you resolve those errors/warning, you should be in good shape. Focus on creating a valid HTML document and you shouldn't have to rebuild your site.